# Finding the supremum of two images in opencv

Tags: opencv

Does anyone know hot to get the supremum from 2 images in OpenCV?
The instruction that I am trying to find, in Matlab would look like:

```
A = max(I, J);
```

Where I and J are images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is [exactly the same](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#max) in opencv:

```
Mat I,J;
Mat A = cv::max(I,J);
```